# Why is Chop ignored in Plot?

Tags: plotting, pure-function

I want to plot multiple functions with the same settings side-by-side, so I use the pure function construct (for clarity, I only use one function in this example)

```
Plot[
   #,
   {x, 0, 1}
   ] & /@
{
   Chop[x, 0.5]
}
```

however, it somehow ignores the Chop function:

[image]

If I plot the function directly

```
Plot[
   Chop[x, 0.5],
   {x, 0, 1}
]
```

everything works as expected:

[image]

I get similar behaviour with Plot3D. Do you see a problem in my code? Does the pure function and Map mechanism (/@) have something to do with it?

PS: I, in fact, want to use Plot3D. That's why I want to draw multiple plots next to each other instead of plotting all functions within one graphics object. I only chose showing the problem using Plot function in order to make the example simpler.

Comment: Check the output of `Chop[x, 0.5]`... now you can see that the solution is to prevent `Chop[...]` inside the `{...}` from being evaluated until it is "inside" `Plot`. Now try with `Unevaluated@Chop[x, 0.5]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Chop[x, 0.5]` evaluates to `x` because `x` is symbolic and not a number. Hence your map is equivalent to

```
Plot[...] & /@ {x}
```

which is what you see. The solution then is to prevent `Chop` from evaluating until it is "inside" `Plot` and this can be done with `Unevaluated`:

```
Plot[#, {x, 0, 1}] & /@ {Unevaluated@Chop[x, 0.5]}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your valuable explanation! Now it works like a charm.